# Error: this.infoWindowFunction is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I simply trying to make a function call with parameters, however, I am having the error mentioned in the subject. My function declaration and call should be ok if you see how I do it below.

I have tried the following but nothing works:

- infoWindowFunction =function( infoWindow, content, marker, map){...}
- infoWindowFunction( infoWindow, content, marker, map){...}
- infoWindowFunction=( infoWindow, content, marker, map) => {...}
- and even the changes below which seems to be the fix as I am no longer having the error but simply not working as intended:

```
let obj={infoWindowFunction: function( infoWindow, content, marker, map)  {
      marker.addListener("click", function (e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(content);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }}

obj.infoWindowFunction( infoWindow,content, map, marker);
```

Here is my self contained sample code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-directions',
  templateUrl: './directions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./directions.component.css']
})

export class DirectionsComponent implements OnInit {

  directionsForm: FormGroup;
  map: google.maps.Map;
  errMess: string;
  markerArray = [];
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ suppressMarkers: true });

  @ViewChild('dform', { static: false }) directionsFormDirective;
  @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,//FormBuilders is an array of groups(i.e. Name, email, Address (new form group as address can be separated further like state, city, etc.))
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.5793, 73.8143),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    this.directionsRenderer.setMap(this.map);
  }

  formErrors = {
    'origin': '',
    'destination': ''
  };

  validationMessages = {
    'origin': {
      'required': 'Please provide origin address'
    },
    'destination': {
      'required': 'Please provide destination address'
    }
  };

  createForm() {
    this.directionsForm = this.fb.group({
      origin: ['', [Validators.required]],
      destination: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });

    this.directionsForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now

  }

  onValueChanged(data?: any) { //data parameter is optional by use of "?"
    if (!this.directionsForm) { return; }
    const form = this.directionsForm;
    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      if (this.formErrors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        // clear previous error message (if any)
        this.formErrors[field] = '';
        const control = form.get(field);
        if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
          const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
          for (const key in control.errors) {
            if (control.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) { //condition unnecessary?
              this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {

    this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(this.directionsService, this.directionsRenderer, this.map, this.infowindow);
  }
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer, map, infowindow) {
    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: { query: this.directionsForm.get('origin').value },
        destination: { query: this.directionsForm.get('destination').value },
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      },

      function (response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          //console.log(response);
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          //this.showSteps(response, infowindow, map, this.markerArray);
          //---------------------Origin Marker----------------------------
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location,
            title: response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address
          });
          var content =
            'Formatted Address: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address +
            '<br/>Location Type: ' + response.geocoded_waypoints[0].types +
            '<br/>Place ID: ' + response.geocoded_waypoints[0].place_id;
          this.infoWindowFunction( infoWindow,content, map, marker);

          //---------------------Destination Marker----------------------------
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location,
            title: response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address
          });
          var content =
              'Formatted Address: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address +
              '<br/>Location Type: ' + response.geocoded_waypoints[1].types +
              '<br/>Place ID: ' + response.geocoded_waypoints[1].place_id;
          this.infoWindowFunction( infoWindow,content, map, marker);
 } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
  }

    infoWindowFunction=( infoWindow, content, marker, map) => {
      marker.addListener("click", function (e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(content);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
```

The reason why I believe that it should work is because on my other component, my function declaration and call works as intended. But I guess the difference is that I am calling a function within a function compared to below.

```
onSubmit() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.geocodeAddress(geocoder, this.map, this.infowindow);
    this.geocodingFormDirective.resetForm();
    this.geocodingForm.reset({
      input: ''
    });
  }

   geocodeAddress=(geocoder, resultsMap, infowindow) =>{
      var address=this.geocodingForm.get('input').value;
      geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: resultsMap,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title: results[0].formatted_address
          });

          marker.addListener("click", function(e) {
                //info Window
                var content = 
                    'Formatted Address: '+results[0].formatted_address+
                    '<br/>Location Type: '+results[0].geometry.location_type+ 
                    '<br/>Address Type: '+results[0].types+ 
                    '<br/>Place ID: '+results[0].place_id;

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: content
                });
                infoWindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
            });
        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
```

Can someone tell me as to why I am having that error or what I am doing wrong? Was my last changes the real answer to my problem?

Error Msg:

> Error: this.infoWindowFunction is not a function

Answer (score 0):

In your `calculateAndDisplayRoute` function, instead of `function` keyword, use `=>` syntax.

```
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer, map, infowindow) {
  directionsService.route(
    {
      origin: { query: this.directionsForm.get('origin').value },
      destination: { query: this.directionsForm.get('destination').value },
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    },

    (response, status) => {   //<----- use arrow function instead of `function` keyword
      if (status === 'OK') {
        //console.log(response);
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        //this.showSteps(response, infowindow, map, this.markerArray);
        //---------------------Origin Marker----------------------------
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location,
          title: response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address
        });
        var content =
          'Formatted Address: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address +
          '<br/>Location Type: ' + response.geocoded_waypoints[0].types +
          '<br/>Place ID: ' + response.geocoded_waypoints[0].place_id;
        this.infoWindowFunction(infoWindow, content, map, marker);

        //---------------------Destination Marker----------------------------
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location,
          title: response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address
        });
        var content =
          'Formatted Address: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address +
          '<br/>Location Type: ' + response.geocoded_waypoints[1].types +
          '<br/>Place ID: ' + response.geocoded_waypoints[1].place_id;
        this.infoWindowFunction(infoWindow, content, map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
}
```